# How to change the background color of jquery mobile footer?

Tags: jquery, ios, css, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am using jquerymobile to build an PhoneGap app for iOS,I try to change the background of jquerymobile but I can't. 
Here is my html source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.css" />

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="mainUI.css"/>


    </head>
    <body>

        <div data-role="page" id='mypage'>
            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
                <h1>Page Title</h1>
                <a data-role="button" data-rel="back">back</a>
            </div><!-- /header -->

            <div data-role="content">
                content
            </div><!-- /content -->
            <div class="my-footer" style="background-color: #00FF00;" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
                <div class="my-tabbar">
                    MYTEST div
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /page -->
    </body>
</html>
```

and here is my custom CSS file:

```
.my-footer {
    background-color:   #ff0000;    
}
.my-footer .my-tabbar{
    background-color:   #ff0000;
}
.my-tabbar{
    background-color: #ff00ff;
}
```

When I ran this html on Chrome browser, I worked. But When I ran on iPhone5 device, it didn't.
Please helps.

Comment: Did you try `!important` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried, but nothing changes. `.my-footer .my-tabbar{
    background-color:   #ff0000 !important;
}
`

Comment: Try overriding the entire background. `background: #ff0000 !important;` to figure out the problem. I think that it's a css issue and not phonegap doing something to the footer.

Comment: try  to override .ui-bar-a  class

Comment: I tried this: '.my-footer .my-tabbar{
    background:transparent url(../../res/img/menu_over.png) !important;
}
' But it still doesn't work on iPHone, It just work on desktop browser like chrome, safari

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the actual jQuery footer mobile selectors. You can use Safari web inspector on an with an iPhone to find the exact selectors for anything and change it accordingly in your own stylesheet.

Here are some selectors I think would do the job:

.ui-bar-a.ui-footer {

```
/*Change background here */
```

}

P.S In your stylesheet, if you want to overide jQuery mobile, make your selectors more specific. **So instead of...**

.ui-bar-a.ui-footer {

```
/*Change background here */
```

}

**Use....**

.my-footer.ui-bar-a.ui-footer {

```
/*Change background here */
```

}

**Or....**

.home-page .ui-bar-a.ui-footer {

```
/*Change background here */
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Thank to my co-worker, I finally found the root cause. When I test this html file with PC browsers, I double click on it. So it runs as a normal html file, which will load all declared resources inside `<header>` tag. But when I test on iPhone, I navigate to this html file from another page by using `$.mobile.changePage()`, which will load the content of `<body>` tag only. At this situation, my `css` file wasn't loaded. That's the reason why my page doesn't work on iPhone.

So, to fix this problem, I just need to move all resources declarations (inside `<head>`) to the bottom of `<body>` tag. By this way, the resource files will be always loaded.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Why bother manually editing CSS and messing up the framework. JQuery Mobile offers a elegant solution to change the color theme of the JQM elements such as header, footer, buttons etc.

Have you heard of [Theme Roller](http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/index.php)? Theme roller will let you import the color of yoru choice to your UI elements. Add your colors and import the css file into the project and change the `data-theme` element to the swatch you used in the Theme Roller.

I personally recommend your custom themes after the Swatch “g” and import your css file before the jQuery mobile css file.

Comment: Theme Roller is pretty limited... I've tried for example to theme the list divider, and I can't... and there are more examples... I think that's why so many people works with css directly.